# SAS- observation1 minus observation2

Tags: sas

I want to calculate that Price at time *t* minus Price at time *t+1* for security *i* at day *k*. Particularly, *t+1* is defined as the price at least 5 min after the price at time *t*. Hence, I added an variable to regulate the interval and used following code to create a row of Price at time *t+1*.
Here is the sample of input data.

```
    data test4;
       length _ric$ 25 type$ 5 interval$ 15 time_l_$ 25 ;
       input _ric$ date_l_ time_l_  type$ price interval$;
       datalines;
      AXPA031407800.U   20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8 09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8 09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8 09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8 09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:34.990 Trade   5.8 09:50:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.011 Trade   5.7 09:55:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:37:58.420 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:39:04.996 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:39:04.996 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:39:04.996 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:39:04.996 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
    AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:39:04.996 Trade   6.25    09:35:00
;

data test1;
  set test nobs=nobs;
  do _i = _n_ to nobs until (new_date ne date_l_ or new_time > interval);
    set test (rename=(date_l_=new_date price=new_price interval=new_time)) point=_i;
  end;
  if (date_l_ ne new_date) or (_i > nobs) then call missing(new_price);  
  run;
```

The output data is shown as following. However, the _RIC (security name), date_l_, and time_l_ are changed. As shown in output data, for example, AXPA031407800.U has 13 observations in input data but 7 observations in output data.

```
_ric    type    interval    time_l_ date_l_ price   new_date    new_time    new_price
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.85    20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.85    20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.8 20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.8 20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.8 20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.8 20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U Trade   09:50:00    9:55:12.990 20131212    5.8 20131212    09:55:00    5.7
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:55:00    9:37:58.420 20131212    5.7 20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00    
AXPA031407900.U Trade   09:35:00    9:39:04.996 20131205    6.25    20131205    09:35:00
```

Here is my target results that create a new variable, Price_next_interval. The new variable represents the price in next interval at the same day.

```
_RIC            Date_l_     time_l_         type    Price   interval    Price_next_interval
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:34.990 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.011 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:37:58.420 Trade   6.25    09:35:00    6.28
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:45:04.996 Trade   6.28    09:45:00    6.29
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:45:04.996 Trade   6.28    09:45:00    6.29
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output data in plain text format. Otherwise, you're effectively asking for people to transcribe your data for you.

Comment: I added a sample of input and output data, thanks

Comment: That's great - please could you also add a sample of what your desired output looks like?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I provide a desired output that create a new variable to represent the price in next interval at the same day.

Comment: If there are multiple prices during the next interval, which one do you want to use?

Comment: The first one is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier to do via by-group processing and `retain` rather than `point`, in my opinion:

```
    data test4;
       length _ric$ 25 type$ 5;
       input _ric $ date_l_ :yymmdd8. time_l_ :time.  type$ price interval :time. price_next_interval_goal;
       format date_l_ yymmddn8. time_l_ interval time.;
       datalines;
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:52:56.537 Trade   5.85    09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.586 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:13.607 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:53:34.990 Trade   5.8     09:50:00    5.7
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:12.990 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.002 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407800.U 20131212    9:55:13.011 Trade   5.7     09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:37:58.420 Trade   6.25    09:35:00    6.28
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:45:04.996 Trade   6.28    09:45:00    6.29
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:45:04.996 Trade   6.28    09:45:00    6.29
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
AXPA031407900.U 20131205    9:55:04.996 Trade   6.29    09:55:00    .
;

/* Sort into reverse order */
proc sort data = v_want out = want;
    by descending date_l_ interval;
run;

/* Carry the price forward via retain if we've got to the last row for this interval  */
/* N.B. do not populate retained figure until after the row has been output*/
/* Clear the carried-forward figure at the start of each date*/
data want2;
set test4;
by descending date_l_ descending interval;
if first.date_l_ then call missing(price_next_interval);
output;
retain price_next_interval;
if last.interval then price_next_interval = price;
run;

/*Sort back into original order*/
proc sort data = want2;
by descending date_l_ interval;
run;
```